# Rebind detailtable in radgrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid

i have a radgrid with detailtables ,

detailTable has "GridEditCommandColumn"  and another "GridTemplateColumn" that contains linkbutton to remove row ,

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="FEATURE_ID">
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FEATURE_ID" UniqueName="FeatureID" ></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>

    <DetailTables>
        <telerik:GridTableView ShowHeader="true" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
            SkinID="RadGridSkin" Width="100%" runat="server" Name="Fees"
            EditMode="InPlace">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FEE_TEMPLATE_ID" UniqueName="FeeID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="DeleteFee">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="RemoveFee" runat="server" CommandName="RemoveFee" Text="RemoveFee" ImageUrl="../../../images/cancel.png" ToolTip="<%$Resources:Strings,remove  %>" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>

        </telerik:GridTableView>
    </DetailTables>

</MasterTableView>
```

in code behind in itemCommand event : 
dataSource of radgrid is updated and Datable.acceptchanges() is called ;

how to rebind only the detailTable where changes have occurred ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't supply the name of your `RadGrid`, but the first thing I would try is:

```
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables(0).Rebind(),
```

or, although I'm not sure whether this works for you (it compiles in VS for me), you might be able to say:

```
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables("Fees").Rebind().
```

Obviously, replace `'RadGrid1'` with the name of your RadGrid.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jan, this was my first post.  Now I know how to do code blocks. :)

Comment: thanks Stonewall_Gary , the right answer is : 

RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables[0].Rebind();